# What information can I get from a hash?

Tags: etherscan, hash, cryptography, keccak

Say i have a hash - I think sha256/keccak:

```
90ad6dec4ce7167e92c7a7122232d48a1fd5e6c5e81cb3f45c147424b6728437
```

What do i do with it?
Is there something on etherscan that can decipher it or show what it is?

I checked and it’s not like a block or address or anything so I assume it’s a message hash and i need a key?

Just curious what to do with this information.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `sha256` or `keccak256` hash, you can only use it as a reference. There's no way to "decode" or "decipher" a hash. But given the original message, you can hash it and check that the reference belongs to that message.

If you don't know where it came from, well, I think there's nothing you can do with it. For you, it's just random bytes with no meaningful value.

There's no way for you to get to the original message from this hash. Unless the original message was really simply and you start brute forcing a lot of possible messages through `keccak256` or `sha256` to see if the resulting hash is the same as this one. But this is time consume and if the original message was complex, I don't think you could ever guess it.